# Send multiple emails with mandrill

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I have a database of subscribers to whom I would like to send the same e-mail. I am using Mandrill to be able to send the e-mails. The Admin of the website has to enter the subject, message and attachment of the e-mail and then submit it to send to all subscribers.

I have tried doing a while loop that runs the Mandrill API for every email in the database. It works, but the server gets exhausted and crashes after sending around 5 emails.

I also know that to be able to run the Mandrill API once and send multiple emails, the "to" array within the Mandrill API has to be repeated for every email address. The thing I am trying to do is to get some kind of a loop that repeats the "to" array for every email within the Mandrill API, thus running the whole API once and sending all the emails. Below is the Mandrill API that I am using to send the emails.

Can you guys help please help me?

Thanks

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
            $ID = $row['ID'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $surname = $row['surname'];
            $email = $row['email'];

            try
            {   
                $mandrill = new Mandrill('My Key');

                $message = array(
                    'html' => $message,
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    'from_email' => 'email@gmail.com',
                    'from_name' => 'Silvan Theuma',
                    'to' => array(
                        array(
                            'email' => $email,
                            'name' => $name,
                            'type' => 'to'
                        )
                    ),/*This is what I want to repeat for every email*/
                    'attachments' => array(
                        array(
                            'type' => $mimeType,
                            'name' => $attachmentName,
                            'content' => $file_encoded
                        )
                    ),                     
                );
            $async = false;
            $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
            $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool);
            }

            catch(Mandrill_Error $e) 
            {
                // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
                echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
                // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
                throw $e;
            }
       }
```

Comment: what Mandrill library are you using?

Comment: I am using the PHP library downloaded from their site

Answer (score 2):

Build the array of recipients in the `while` loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $recipients[] = array(
        'email' => $row['email'],
        'name' => $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'],
        'type' => 'to'
    );
}
```

And pass it to the mandrill construct

```
try{   
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('My Key');

    $message = array(
        'html' => $message,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'from_email' => 'email@gmail.com',
        'from_name' => 'Silvan Theuma',
        'to' => $recipients, // here
        'preserve_recipients' => false,
        'attachments' => array(
            array(
                'type' => $mimeType,
                'name' => $attachmentName,
                'content' => $file_encoded
            )
        ),                     
    );

    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool);
}

catch(Mandrill_Error $e){
    // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
    throw $e;
}
```

And make sure to add `preserve_recipients` to false in the `$message` array.

> preserve_recipients: whether or not to expose all recipients in to "To" header for each email

Comment: did you try it? the `to` array does not get repeated, it's an array containing a list of recipients

Comment: Yes sorry for the previous message it was a mistake I did with the code